# std::unordered_set::equal_range iterator question

Tags: c++, c++11, iterator, c++14, language-lawyer

`std::unordered_set::equal_range` returns a pair of iterators describing the range of values in the set where the keys for the values compare as equal. Given:

```
auto iteratorFromEqualRange = someUnorderedSet.equal_range(key).first;
auto iteratoFromFind = someUnorderedSet.find(key);
```

is it guaranteed by the Standard that:

```
++iteratorFromEqualRange == ++iteratorFromFind;
```

as they are both defined in terms of `std::unordered_set::iterator`?  In other words, can a different implementation of `std::unordered_set` keep "hidden" information about the *context* of what we're iterating, or is this a not-very-subtle enforcement of the bucket interface (which limits our implementation options)?

I expect that this is indeed a guarantee, given the requirements of *LegacyForwardIterator*, I'm just asking for confirmation (or better news that includes some kind of escape hatch)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iterator of `unordered_set` is a Forward Iterator (now named [*LegacyForwardIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/ForwardIterator)).

The C++14 standard (final draft n4140) states this regarding Forward Iterators:

> **24.2.5 Forward iterators [forward.iterators]**
>
> 1 A class or pointer type `X` satisfies the requirements of a forward iterator if
>   ...
>   (1.5) — objects of type `X` **offer the multi-pass guarantee**, described below.
>   ...
>
> 3 Two ***dereferenceable*** iterators `a` and `b` of type `X` offer the multi-pass guarantee if:
>
> (3.1) — **`a == b` implies `++a == ++b`** and
>   (3.2) — `X` is a pointer type or the expression `(void)++X(a)`, `*a` is equivalent to the expression `*a`.

Combining (1.5) and (3.1) in this case would mean that `++iteratorFromEqualRange == ++iteratorFromFind;` is guaranteed by the standard, provided both these iterators can be dereferenced.

Comment: @P,W. That was my reading of it, too. That sucks. I was hoping someone could point out a loophole or something, but the multi-pass guarantee is one of the areas of the standard that's pretty straightforward. Accepting this as the answer (which means admitting defeat for my library conforming as closely as possible to the standard as I had wished, but c'est la vie).